# Bootstrap Version 4.5.0: Tabs in Tab: Unable to get the tabs/navs to behave correctly

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am unable to get the `tabs in tab` working. I am trying to use `article`, `section` instead of the usual `div.` Not sure if CSS for `section` from Bootstrap is messing up or I need some JavaScript to take care of business!

I looked at other posts; They use earlier versions `(2)` of bootstrap. But I am using `v.4.5.0.` Appreciate any/all help.

Here is my complete page/code

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Tabs in Tab</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="Server Panel">
    <meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="/images/icons/144x144.png">
    <meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#2F3BA2">
    <meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="true">
    <meta name="Robots" content="INDEX,FOLLOW">
    <meta name="Rating" content="General">
    <meta name="author" content="webmaster@HostLawn.com">
    <meta name="description" content="sPanel">
    <meta name="keywords" content="Server Panel, control panel, cpanel, sPanel">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="black">
    <link rel="favicon" href="favicon.ico">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/images/icons/152x152.png">
    <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <style>

        body {
            font-size: 1rem;
        }

        .ads {
            min-height: 7em;
        }

            .ads h4 {
                margin: 0.5em 0 0.5em 0;
                padding: 0.2em;
                font-size: 0.7em;
                text-align: center;
                background: radial-gradient(circle, #f5f5f0, #ebebe0);
                color: green;
            }

        .inv {
            display: none;
        }

        h1, h2, h3, h4, h5 {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        h2 {
            background: radial-gradient(circle, #f5f5f0, #ebebe0);
            height: auto;
            font-weight: bold;
            width: 100%;
            padding: 0.3em;
            margin: 0 0 0.5em 0;
        }

        h1 {
            font-size: 1.4em;
            margin: 0;
            background-color: inherit;
        }

        header {
            min-height: 3rem;
        }

            header h2 {
                display: none;
            }

        main {
            clear: both;
        }

        article {
            margin: 0 0 1em 0;
            padding: 0 0 0em 1em;
            clear: both;
        }

            article h2 {
                font-size: 1.3em;
            }

            article h3 {
                font-size: 1.2em;
                background: radial-gradient(circle, #f5f5f0, #ebebe0);
                height: auto;
                font-weight: bold;
                width: 100%;
                padding: 0.3em;
                margin: 0.5em 0 0.5em 0;
            }

            article h4 {
                font-size: 1.1em;
            }

            article h5 {
                font-size: 1.0em;
            }

        .ready {
            font-weight: bold;
        }

        .quicklinks {
            margin: 0.1rem;
            padding: 0.2rem 0 0 0.8rem;
            text-align: right;
        }

            .quicklinks a {
                font-size: 1.2rem;
                padding: 0 0.2em 0 0.2em;
            }

        .clock {
            position: relative;
            transform: translateX(-1%) translateY(-1%);
            font-size: 14px;
            font-family: Orbitron;
            letter-spacing: 2px;
            margin: 0.1rem;
            padding: 0.2rem 0 0 0.8rem;
        }

        .your-ads-here {
            font-family: Georgia, serif;
            padding: 0.3rem;
            margin: 0.3rem 0 0 0;
            text-align: center;
            background-color: rgba(0, 128, 0, 0.1);
            color: teal;
            clear: both;
            min-height: 3rem;
        }

        .tabs-height {
            min-height: 10rem;
            overflow-x: auto;
            overflow-y: auto;
        }

        textarea {
            width: 100%;
            min-height: 12rem;
        }

        .my-card-in-tab {
            width: auto;
            height: auto;
            margin: 0.5rem;
            padding: 0.8rem;
            float: left;
            clear: right;
            border: 1px dotted silver;
        }

        .mycard {
            width: auto;
            height: auto;
            margin: 0.5rem;
            padding: 0.8rem;
            float: left;
            border: 1px dotted gray;
        }

            .mycard .mycard-text {
                border-bottom: 0px dotted silver;
                margin: 0.3rem 0 0.3rem 0;
            }

            .mycard .mycard-title {
                font-weight: bold;
                clear: both;
            }

            .mycard a {
                font-size: 1.2rem;
                padding: 0.2rem;
                color: black;
            }

                .mycard a:hover {
                    background-color: lightgreen;
                    font-size: 1.2rem;
                    padding: 0.2rem;
                }

            .mycard textarea {
                overflow: auto;
            }

        .main-tabs {
            padding: 0.7rem;
        }

        article section article section {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <h1 class="inv">sPanel</h1>

    <nav class="navbar sticky-top navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">

        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#" title="click to refresh - app home">sPanel</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link active" href="/login" title="Login to Track Your Steps">Login</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="/register" title="Register to Track Your Steps">Register</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                        Menu
                    </a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="/login">Login</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="/register">Register</a>
                        <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="/about">About</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="/author">Author</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="/advertise">Advertise</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="/purchase">Purchase</a>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0" action="/search">
                <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <header class="container-flex">
        <h2>Desc</h2>
    </header>

    <main class="main">

        <section class="row">
            <h2 class="inv">User and Clock</h2>
            <div class="col-5" id="MyClockDisplay"></div>
            <article class="col-7" style="text-align:right;">
                <h2 title="Quick links for mobile devices" class="inv">Quick Links</h2>
                <a href="/" title="Home">Home</a>
                <a href="/login" title="Login">Login</a>
                <a href="/register" title="Register">Register</a> &nbsp;
            </article>
            
        </section>

        <article class="container-flex">
            <h2 class="inv">Options for Master Admin</h2>
            <div class="card-deck">
                <!-- content:cards -->
            </div>
        </article>

        <article class="container-flex tabs-height">
            <h2 class="inv">Web Master</h2>

            <ul class="nav nav-pills" id="myTab" role="tablist">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link active" id="home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#home" role="tab" aria-controls="home" aria-selected="true">
                        Users
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" id="profile-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#profile" role="tab" aria-controls="profile" aria-selected="false">
                        Logs
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a title="Edit all kinds of files" class="nav-link" id="vs-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#vs" role="tab" aria-controls="vs" aria-selected="false">
                        Edit
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" id="dns-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#dns" role="tab" aria-controls="contact" aria-selected="false">
                        DNS
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" id="letsencrypt-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#letsencrypt" role="tab" aria-controls="letsencrypt" aria-selected="false" title="Lets Encrypt">
                        LE
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" id="mail-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#mail" role="tab" aria-controls="mail" aria-selected="false" title="eMail">
                        Mail
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>

            <section class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">

                <article class="tab-pane fade show main-tabs" id="home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab">
                    <h3 class="inv">Tab 1 Content</h3>

                    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="t_nav1" role="tablist">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link active" id="t_nav1_a" data-toggle="tab" href="#t_tab1_a" role="tab" aria-controls="t_tab1_a" aria-selected="true">
                                View
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" id="t_nav1_b" data-toggle="tab" href="#t_tab1_b" role="tab" aria-controls="t_tab1_b" aria-selected="false">
                                Edit
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a title="Edit all kinds of files" class="nav-link" id="t_nav1_c" data-toggle="tab" href="#t_tab1_c" role="tab" aria-controls="t_tab1_c" aria-selected="false">
                                Del
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>

                </article>
                <article class="tab-content" id="t_tab1">

                    <section class="tab-pane fade show" id="t_tab1_a" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="t_nav1_a">
                        <h4 class="inv">Tab 1-1 Content</h4>
                        View
                    </section>
                    <section class="tab-pane fade" id="t_tab1_b" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="t_nav1_b">
                        Edit
                    </section>
                    <section class="tab-pane fade" id="t_tab1_c" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="t_nav1_c">
                        Delete
                    </section>

                </article>

                <article class="tab-pane fade main-tabs" id="profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="profile-tab">
                    <h3 class="inv">Tab 2 Content</h3>

                    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="t_nav2" role="tablist">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link " id="t_nav2_a" data-toggle="tab" href="#t_tab2_a" role="tab" aria-controls="t_tab2_a" aria-selected="true">
                                sPanel
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" id="t_nav2_b" data-toggle="tab" href="#t_tab2_b" role="tab" aria-controls="t_tab2_b" aria-selected="false">
                                2
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a title="Edit all kinds of files" class="nav-link" id="t_nav2_c" data-toggle="tab" href="#t_tab2_c" role="tab" aria-controls="t_tab2_c" aria-selected="false">
                                3
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>

                </article>
                <article class="tab-content" id="t_tab2">

                    <section class="tab-pane fade " id="t_tab2_a" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="t_nav2_a">
                        <h4 class="inv">Tab 2-1 Content</h4>
                        <div class="mycard">
                            <textarea cols="40" rows="10" wrap="soft">log_app</textarea>
                        </div>
                    </section>
                    <section class="tab-pane fade" id="t_tab2_b" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="t_nav2_b">
                        <h4 class="inv">Tab 2-2 Content</h4>
                        <div class="mycard"><textarea cols="40" rows="10" wrap="soft">messages</textarea></div>
                    </section>
                    <section class="tab-pane fade" id="t_tab2_c" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="t_nav2_c">
                        <h4 class="inv">Tab 2-3 Content</h4>
                        <div class="mycard"><textarea cols="40" rows="10" wrap="soft">Apache Server</textarea></div>
                    </section>

                </article>

                <article class="tab-pane fade main-tabs" id="vs" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="vs-tab">
                    <h3 class="inv">Tab 3 Content</h3>

                    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="t_nav3" role="tablist">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" id="t_nav3_a" data-toggle="tab" href="#t_tab3_a" role="tab" aria-controls="t_tab3_a" aria-selected="true">
                                Nginx
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" id="t_nav3_b" data-toggle="tab" href="#t_tab3_b" role="tab" aria-controls="t_tab3_b" aria-selected="false">
                                Apache
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a title="Edit all kinds of files" class="nav-link" id="t_nav3_c" data-toggle="tab" href="#t_tab3_c" role="tab" aria-controls="t_tab3_c" aria-selected="false">
                                App
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a title="Edit all kinds of files" class="nav-link" id="t_nav3_d" data-toggle="tab" href="#t_tab3_d" role="tab" aria-controls="t_tab3_d" aria-selected="false">
                                Postfix
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a title="Edit all kinds of files" class="nav-link" id="t_nav3_e" data-toggle="tab" href="#t_tab3_e" role="tab" aria-controls="t_tab3_e" aria-selected="false">
                                Bind
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>

                </article>
                <article class="tab-content" id="t_tab3">

                    <section class="tab-pane fade show" id="t_tab3_a" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="t_nav3_a">
                        <h4 class="inv">Tab 3-1 Content</h4>
                        <div>
                            <a href="/admin/edit/nginx" title="Edit nginx.conf">Nginx</a>
                            <a href="/admin/create/nginx" title="Create New Nginx server">New</a>
                        </div>

                    </section>
                    <section class="tab-pane fade" id="t_tab3_b" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="t_nav3_b">
                        <h4 class="inv">Tab 3-2 Content</h4>
                        <div>
                            <a href="/admin/edit/httpd" title="Edit httpd.conf">Httpd</a>
                            <a href="/admin/create/httpd" title="Create New Httpd server">New</a>
                        </div>

                    </section>
                    <section class="tab-pane fade" id="t_tab3_c" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="t_nav3_c">
                        <h4 class="inv">Tab 3-3 Content</h4>
                        app files

                    </section>
                    <section class="tab-pane fade" id="t_tab3_d" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="t_nav3_d">
                        <h4 class="inv">Tab 3-4 Content</h4>
                        <div>
                            <a href="/admin/edit/main.cf" title="Postfx main.cf">main.cf</a>
                        </div>
                        Postfix files

                    </section>
                    <section class="tab-pane fade" id="t_tab3_e" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="t_nav3_e">
                        <h4 class="inv">Tab 3-5 Content</h4>
                        <div>
                            <a href="/admin/edit/etc/named.conf" title="Edit named.conf">named.conf</a>
                            <a href="/admin/named/new" title="Add new .dns file">New</a>
                        </div>

                    </section>

                </article>


                <article class="tab-pane fade main-tabs" id="dns" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="dns-tab">
                    <h3 class="inv">Tab 4 content</h3>
                    <h2>?</h2>
                    <div>
                        <a href="" title="">?</a>
                    </div>
                </article>

                <article class="tab-pane fade main-tabs" id="letsencrypt" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="letsencrypt-tab">
                    <h3 class="inv">Tab 5 Content</h3>
                    <form action="/admin/letsencrypt" method="post">
                        Domain 1 <input type="text" name="domain1" value=".hostlawn.com"> <br />
                        Domain 2 <input type="text" name="domain2" value=".hostlawn.com"> <br />
                        Domain 3 <input type="text" name="domain3" value=".hostlawn.com"> <br />
                        Domain 4 <input type="text" name="domain4" value=".hostlawn.com"> <br />
                        <input type="submit" value="Get Certificate">
                    </form>
                </article>

                <article class="tab-pane fade main-tabs" id="mail" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="mail-tab">
                    <h3 class="inv">Tab 6 Content</h3>
                    Tab 6
                </article>

            </section>

        </article>

        <article class="container error">
            <h2 class="inv">Errors</h2>
        </article>

</main>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha256-4+XzXVhsDmqanXGHaHvgh1gMQKX40OUvDEBTu8JcmNs=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-1CmrxMRARb6aLqgBO7yyAxTOQE2AKb9GfXnEo760AUcUmFx3ibVJJAzGytlQcNXd" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover()
        })

        $('.popover-dismiss').popover({
            trigger: 'focus'
        })

        function activateTab(tab){
            $('.nav-tabs a[href="#' + tab + '"]').tab('show');
        };

        // register service worker
        if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
                window.addEventListener('load', () => {
                navigator.serviceWorker.register("sw.js")
                .then((reg) => {
                console.log("sPanel registered.", reg);
                });
            });
        }

        //Clock
        function showTime(){
        var date = new Date();

        var yr = date.getFullYear();
        var mo = date.getMonth(); //mo += 1;
        var dy = date.getDate();

        var h = date.getHours(); // 0 - 23
        var m = date.getMinutes(); // 0 - 59
        var s = date.getSeconds(); // 0 - 59

        var days = new Array();
        days = ["Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"];
        var dayNum = date.getDay();
            //dayNum -= 1;
        var dayName = days[dayNum];

        var months = new Array();
        months = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"];
        var monthName = months[mo];

        var session = "AM";

        if(h == 0){
            h = 12;
        }

        if(h > 12){
            h = h - 12;
            session = "PM";
        }

        h = (h < 10) ? "0" + h : h;
        m = (m < 10) ? "0" + m : m;
        s = (s < 10) ? "0" + s : s;

        var time = '';
        // ymd
        //time += yr + '-' + mo + '-' + dy + ' ';
        //
        time += ' ' +months[mo]+ ' ' +dy+ ' ' +dayName+ ' ';
        // hms
        time += h + ":" + m + ":" + s + " " + session;
        document.getElementById("MyClockDisplay").innerText = time;
        //document.getElementById("MyClockDisplay").textContent = time;

        setTimeout(showTime, 1000);

    }
showTime();
// end clock

            //$('#t_nav1 a').on('click', function (e) { e.preventDefault() $(this).tab('show') });
            //$('#t_nav2 a').on('click', function (e) { e.preventDefault() $(this).tab('show') });
            //$('#t_nav3 a').on('click', function (e) { e.preventDefault() $(this).tab('show') });

        </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You might get help easier if you trim down the included code a bit into a proper [mcve]

Comment: This is actually a trimmed down version of my theme from the project. 

The page is actually live/accessible at https://gap.hostlawn.com/server/tabs-in-tab.html

Comment: I understand it's a lot. The actual page is 51k. The trimmed down version is 19k!